# Elasticsearch inline script : can we use ctx._source field1 transforming data type assigning to ctx._source field2

Tags: elasticsearch

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NE8G.png
as the pic displayed, how can i migrate field a to field b which data type is not same

Comment: What type is `test`? Can you show some sample values?

Comment: @Val thank u for answering my question, i've solved this by using scripts just like:"script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.test = Integer.parseInt(ctx._source.test)" }to solve the field type conflict in new&old index